# Mosquitto: Async connection on Raspberry PI 4 not working

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, mosquitto

I'm struggling using the mosquitto lib on my RaspberryPI 4 in an non-blocking way.

This is may main method:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mosquitto.h>
#include "mqtt.h"
#include <string>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Start\n");
    MqttConnector * mqtt = new MqttConnector("piClient", "send", "rc", 1883, "localhost", 60);
    mqtt->startClient();
    printf("MQTT is started\n");
    while(1)
    {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Important parts of mqtt.cpp**

```
#include "mqtt.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <mosquitto.h>

MqttConnector::MqttConnector(std::string id, std::string sendTopic, std::string receiveTopic, int port, std::string host, int keepalive)
{   
    
    mosquitto_lib_init();
    mosqClient = mosquitto_new(id.c_str(), true, this);
    
    if(!mosqClient){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Out of memory.\n");
    }
    
    this->keepalive = keepalive;
    this->id = id;
    this->host = host;
    this->port = port;
    this->sendTopic = sendTopic;
    this->receiveTopic = receiveTopic;

}

MqttConnector::~MqttConnector()
{
    mosquitto_destroy(mosqClient);
    mosquitto_lib_cleanup();
}

void MqttConnector::messageCallback(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *userdata, const struct mosquitto_message *message)
{   
    
    //MqttConnector * mqttInstance = (MqttConnector *) userdata;
    
    if(message->payloadlen){
        std::string payloadString = reinterpret_cast<char*>(message->payload);
        
        printf("Message arriving in %s : %s\n", message->topic, payloadString.c_str());
        
        std::string rp = "rp";
        if(payloadString == rp)
        {
            mosquitto_publish(mosq, NULL, "send", strlen("test"), "test", 2, false);
        }

    }else{
        printf("Empty message arriving in %s\n", message->topic);
    }
}

void MqttConnector::connectCallback(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *userdata, int result)
{   
    if(!result){
        printf("Connection established\n");
    }else{
        fprintf(stderr, "Connect failed\n");
    }
}

void MqttConnector::logCallback(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *userdata, int level, const char *str)
{
    /* Pring all log messages regardless of level. */
    printf("%s\n", str);
}


void MqttConnector::publishCallback(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *userdata, int usernumber)
{
    printf("Published a message\n");
}

void MqttConnector::startClient()
{
    
    mosquitto_message_callback_set(mosqClient, messageCallback);

    mosquitto_log_callback_set(mosqClient, logCallback);
    mosquitto_connect_callback_set(mosqClient, connectCallback);
    mosquitto_publish_callback_set(mosqClient, publishCallback);    

    /*
    //Connecting without async works! Publish and receiving messages work!
    // loop starts by calling loop_forever
    if(mosquitto_connect(mosqClient, host.c_str(), port, keepalive)){
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to connect.\n");
    }
    
    mosquitto_subscribe(mosqClient, NULL, receiveTopic.c_str(), 2);
    mosquitto_loop_forever(mosqClient, 10, 1);
    */
    
    // According to docu we need to call loop_start instead of forever
    // not able to publish/receive message with this!
    if(mosquitto_connect_async(mosqClient, host.c_str(), port, keepalive)){
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to connect.\n");
    }
    
    mosquitto_subscribe(mosqClient, NULL, receiveTopic.c_str(), 2);
    mosquitto_loop_start(mosqClient);
}
```

Connecting to the server with `mosquitto_connect` and starting the loop with `mosquitto_loop_forever` is the blocking way. Therefore I only see the first print statement in the main.cpp ('Start'). But with this way, I'm able to publish and receive message with that client.

As soon as I connect with `mosquitto_connect_async`, I need to start the loop with `mosquitto_loop_start` as it is mentioned in the documentation. The client connects to the server without an error. And I also see the second print statement from the main.cpp now. But I'm not able to publish oder receive any messages with the mqtt client.
My first guess was that because of the threading, the messages are not printed on the console, but even other clients startet with `mosquitto_sub` don't receive a message from that c++ client.

Do I need to install something for threading support on the RPI4?
I don't understand why it is not working, because the RPI4 supports multithreading.

Thanks for helping

Comment: I'd double check "while(1) {}" isn't eating all of your CPU / not letting other threads yield. Seen it happen before. If you're using c++11, put a std::this_thread::sleep_for() a few milliseconds in the while loop. This will make the main thread yields, and will give other threads in the app a chance to work.

Comment: still not working:/. I put a 1s sleep inside the while but nothing changed

Comment: in the borker terminal I can see the new client connected: New connection from 127.0.0.01 as piClient (p2,c1, k10176),but still I can't receive/publish anything

Comment: Can you find any examples to cross reference your C++ code against??

Comment: I only found example where they are using the blocking "connect" function, not the async connection

Comment: like here https://cpp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/mosquitto_connect/cpp-mosquitto_connect-function-examples.html